# Problem in using CustomActionData while createing installer

Tags: installation

Any one can explain about how to pass install location to installer by code?

Answer (score 0):

Use customactiondata property on your installer project as output to your msi, like:

InstallLoc="[TARGETDIR]\"

and in installer project use code like:

```
installDir = this.Context.Parameters["InstallLoc"];
```